# Mysql data caching with asp.net Web API

Tags: mysql, caching, asp.net-web-api

Is there anyway we can do mysql caching in dotnet web api? Need something like this http://serena-yeoh.blogspot.in/2014/02/runtime-caching-with-sqlchangemonitor.html

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-memcached.html

Comment: Is there any sample available?

Comment: Just search around for caching in MySQL.  This is a well known problem.